# QueryTask doesn't return anything ArcGIs Javascript 3.24

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query

I have a query that I believe I am setting up correctly, but maybe I'm missing a vital property. Does the where clause need to be set? I want to query all features, not a subset of them, so I don't really need a where restriction.

Every time I run this query it goes to the error callback where the message given is unhelpful.

```
printQLyr = new QueryTask("https://xxx/MapServer/3");
printQuery = new Query();
printQuery.returnGeometry = false;
printQuery.outFields = ["Name"];
printQLyr.on("complete", printQResults);
printQLyr.on("error", errorResults);
printQLyr.execute(printQuery);

function printQResults(featureSet) {
    var resultFeatures = featureSet.features;
    console.log(resultFeatures[0]);
}

function errorResults(message) {
    console.log(message);
}
```

What I get back in the console is this:

Error at Object.A.m.load (https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/init.js:1028:392) at https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/init.js:87:429 at c (https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/init.js:103:393) at d (https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/init.js:103:182) at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/init.js:105:10) at c (https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/init.js:104:96) at d (https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/init.js:103:182) at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/init.js:105:10) at https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/init.js:92:118 at h (https://js.arcgis.com/3.24/init.js:107:277)

Comment: Are the ObjectID and Shape fields accessible in your service? Can you run a query on the service page itself?

Comment: @kenbuja Yes, I can run a query on the service page. I can even run the query from my JS web application if I include `printQuery.where` and set it to something, but since I want to query all features, it doesn't make sense to set the where clause. I also see OBJECTID and Shape listed as fields under the "Fields" heading on my rest services page for the service, so I believe that means they're accessible.

Comment: @kenbuja It also runs fine if I set the `printQuery.objectIds` property... It just doesn't work when I have no filters set. I have also just tested this code snippet in the ArcGIS JS Sandbox and I receive the same error there as well.

Comment: The sample in the documentation have either a geometry or some type of where clause. Try using `printQLyr.where "1=1"`

Comment: @kenbuja That worked! Thank you! Add it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Query will need a geometry, objectId, or a where clause to run. To select all features, use

```
printQLyr.where="1=1";
```